# mongodb multiple categories, each with its own hierarchy tree

Tags: mongodb, hierarchical-data

I have a collection `categories` with such schema:

```
_id: ObjectId, name: String, parent: ObjectId
```

and another collection `products`, with a reference:

```
name: String, category: [ObjectId, ObjectId, ...]
```

the `category` array contains a hierarchy tree rather than multiple categories, facilitating the query of higher-level categories.

e.g. category tree A -> B -> C, A is root. When a product is saved, its document is:

```
name: 'some name', category: [C, B, A]
```

So I can fast and easily query all products even for higher-level categories like B or A.

**Now the schema changes, one product can have multiple categories, each category with its hierarchical tree.** 
Naturally I came the following:

```
name: 'some name', categories: [ [C, B, A], [E, D, A], ... ]
```

but the query is difficult and it seems index is impossible. So I need your help.

Comment: Could you query the category to get its hierarchy, and then use $in (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/in/)?

Comment: @WiredPrairie yes, that would be perfectly viable, but it may need too many recursive traversals if the tree is deep and without a cache, so I'm finding a structure similar to my previous one to do this.

Comment: What about `{categories: [C, E], categoryParents: {C: [B, A], E: [D, A]}}`?

Comment: @vinipsmaker How do I query "all products of category A" (including products of A's sub-category)?

Comment: @gfaceless, with my previous suggestion, you can't. And what about `{categories: [C, B, A, E, D, A], categoryLeaves: [C, E]}`? Would this solve your problems?

Comment: @vinipsmaker yes, it solves. I haven't thought of that. Thanks!